# Facebook PHP SDK v4 how to hide the access_token for a page

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, guzzle

I am trying to include the latest 5 posts from my facebook company page to my website.  I can easily facebook as follows:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id]/feed?access_token={facebook_app_id}|
{facebook_app_secret)&limit=5
```

The reply is in json format so I can easily parse and create a view.

How can I avoid exposing my facebook_app_id and facebook_app_secret?

Comment: Make the calls server-side. The app ID is something you can share publicly, though. (See the code generated at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button for an example.)

Comment: Like this?
     try {
        $response = $this->fb->get(
        '/'.$page_id.'/posts',
        $access_token
        );
        
  } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
  } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
  }

  $graphNode = $response->getGraphEdge();
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($graphNode);
  echo "</pre>";
  exit;

Comment: you are using php, so it´s hidden anyway...

Comment: Sorry, did not realize that.  It all checked out.  All hidden.  Thanks.